# Rails 3 ActiveRecord query in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model with a one_to_many relationship to another model such that:

```
user.area_ids = [1, 2, 3]
```

And then another model that shares the relationship but is a one to one.

```
listing.area_id = 1
```

How do I query for all the listings that are either area_id of 1 2 or 3. I am hoping to do something like...

```
Listing.where("area_id IN ?", user.area_ids)
```

But that doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try: `user.area_ids.join(',')`

Comment: @Brian No, that's a very ugly solution. Rails understands how to do `where(field: [1,2,3])` just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're being too clever. Rails understands how to do `where(field: [1,2,3])` just fine.

If you give `where` a regular `key: value` where the value is an array, it will build the `where FIELD in (a,b,c)` for you.

Just use

```
Listing.where(area_id: user.area_ids)  # select ... where area_id in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me as did the other answer. Just for learning's sake -- why should I avoid building query manually. Security issue?

Comment: No, because there is absolutely no need to. Rails can do it, so let Rails do it. The database backend you're using now might use `where in (...)`, but you might decide tomorrow that you want to use a different database, and if you let Rails do what it's good at, your code won't have to change at all. If you've built a bunch of queries by hand, it would be a headache.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What if I want to query the other way around from the User side? I want all the users that have 1 in the user.area_ids (the listing.area_id)?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot braces around question mark :)
try this:

```
Listing.where("area_id IN (?)", user.area_ids)
```

But as for me, more proper way is to make it cleaner with a help of

```
class User 
  has_many :areas
  has_many :listings, through: :areas
end
```

and then just call

```
user.listings
```